# How to get musicbrainz track information from audio file

Tags: c#, audio, fingerprinting, audio-fingerprinting, musicbrainz

Can anyone tell me how to get track information from the [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) database from an audio file (mp3, wav, wma, ogg, etc...) using audio fingerprinting. I'm using MusicBrainz Sharp library, but any other library is ok.

I've seen that you must use the libofa library, that you can't use MusicBrainz Sharp to get puid from the audio file, but I can't figure out how to use libofa with C#.

Please show some examples and code snippets to help me, because I can't find them anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you can probably use [libofa](http://code.google.com/p/musicip-libofa/) to get a fingerprint of the audio file, but if the file has no [PUID](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/HowPUIDsWork) available, you will be stuck and will have to use something like [genpuid](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/genpuid) to submit the audio fingerprint to [AmpliFIND](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/) and wait about a day to get a [PUID](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/PUID).

That being said, I tried something similar about two years ago, but kinda lost interest in the project when I failed to write the IDv3 tags, if I remember correctly. However, the source code is available [on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/hangy/ikulo).

I basically [wrapped libofa](https://bitbucket.org/hangy/ikulo/src/0e61db628f2d/Server/Ikulo.Server.Core/OfaFingerprinter.cs) using a `DllImport` and also [wrapped genpuid](https://bitbucket.org/hangy/ikulo/src/0e61db628f2d/Server/Ikulo.Server.Core/GenpuidFingerprinter.cs) (ie. read the output XML) to be able to read the fingerprint and submit the file for fingerprinting if I did not get one from libofa. I also wrote [some code](https://bitbucket.org/hangy/ikulo/src/0e61db628f2d/Server/Ikulo.Server.Core/MusicBrainzTagger.cs) that reads information from MusicBrainz using [MusicBrainz Sharp](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicbrainzSharp).

Well, at least that was what I planned back then, I think. :) I hope this helps you to solve your problem and I'd love to see an update on this.

*Edit*: I just noticed that I created a [bug report](https://bitbucket.org/hangy/ikulo/issue/6) for myself, which basically says that I still needed an implementation for my [decoder](https://bitbucket.org/hangy/ikulo/src/0e61db628f2d/Server/Ikulo.Server.Core/IDecoder.cs) which is probably why I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143856/) in SO. So I guess I did not implement the [genpuid fingerprinter](https://bitbucket.org/hangy/ikulo/src/0e61db628f2d/Server/Ikulo.Server.Core/GenpuidFingerprinter.cs) just to be able to do the fingerprint/get the guid, because I did not get the [libofa fingerprinter](https://bitbucket.org/hangy/ikulo/src/0e61db628f2d/Server/Ikulo.Server.Core/GenpuidFingerprinter.cs) to work correctly.

Comment: @Baki: Did this help or do you need any further advice?

Comment: To write ID3 tags (do you really mean ID3v3? or id3v2?) you can use taglib. There is a nuget and it is really nice to use.

Comment: TagLib actually didn't work too well with .NET in 2008 (and NuGet did not exist ;)), but I suppose it's gotten better at it's job. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did the wrapped genpuid approach suggested above.

```
    private string GetPUID(string fileName)
    {

        Process p;
        ProcessStartInfo si;
        string outRow;
        string puidReturned;

        string gendPuidPath = @"C:\Program Files\genpuid\genpuid.exe";
        string gendPuidKey = "your key here";
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex puidRex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex( @"puid: (\S+)" ); // sample:  puid: 3c62e009-ec93-1c0f-e078-8829e885df67
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m;

        if (File.Exists(gendPuidPath))
        {
            try
            {
                si = new ProcessStartInfo(gendPuidPath, gendPuidKey + " \"" + fileName + "\"");
                si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                si.UseShellExecute = false;

                p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = si;
                p.Start();

                puidReturned = "";
                while ((outRow = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    m = puidRex.Match(outRow);
                    if (m.Success)
                        puidReturned = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    Debug.WriteLine(outRow);
                }
                p.WaitForExit();
                p.Close();

                return puidReturned;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw new Exception("Unexpexted Error obtaining PUID for file: " + fileName, ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("genpuid.exe not found");
            return "";
        }
    }
```